# What am i doing wrong when I try to call an activity outside an other activity in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, methods, android-activity

I Want to put all my methods in seperate classes to clean my code up when creating my Android App but i can seem to get it right.

In my MainActivity class i call the method from the importet class noteFunctionality onLongpress and OnDoubleTap.

```
            @Override
            public void onLongPress(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {
                noteFunc.enterNote("2");
                super.onLongPress(e);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {
                noteFunc.enterNote(2);
                return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }
```

Then in my NoteFunctionality class i try start the a new activity class with the given int for the specifik activity, "I have more then one activity".

```
    public void enterNote(int i) {
    Class mainActivity = Class.forName("MainActivity" + i);
    Intent secondActivityIntent = new Intent(this, mainActivity.class);
    startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?.

Comment: What happens? Do you get compile or runtime errors? Edit your question and show us what you are seeing.

Comment: The first obvious thing I see is that you cannot use `this` when calling the `Intent` constructor in the method `enterNote`, because `this` is an instance of `NoteFunctionality` and you need an instance of `Context` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void enterNote(Activity activity,Context context) {
    //Class mainActivity = Class.forName("MainActivity" + i);   
    Intent secondActivityIntent = new Intent(context, activity.getClass());
    startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
}
```

and when you call it

```
noteFunc.enterNote(MainActivity,yourActivity.this);
```

Comment: I cant get this working at all. Intent secondActivityIntent = new Intent(context, activity.class); says Unknown class: 'activity'.

Comment: Try activity.getClass()

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to trigger another **Activity**, it must be done through `Context`.

Therefore, you need to pass `Context` to your `NoteFunctionality` function to achieve your task.

**MainActivity**:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity { // or extending any other form of Activity
    NoteFunctionality noteFunc; // I assume you have properly assign it somewhere

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {
        // You will have to pass also Context to enterNote function
        noteFunc.enterNote(MainActivity.this, "2"); // You should pass an Integer instead of String here
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {
        noteFunc.enterNote(MainActivity.this, 2);
        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }
}
```

**NoteFunctionality**:

```java
public class NoteFunctionality {
    // You need to have Context here
    public void enterNote(Context context, int i) {
        Intent secondActivityIntent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class); // Replace your target Activity name with SecondActivity
        context.startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
    }
}
```